# Spherical coordinates in triple integral - problem with infinite conic

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates

I have to calculate integral:

$$ \iiint (x^2+y^2+z^2)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz$$

on the volume bound between the following surfaces:

$$y^2+z^2=x^2$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = a^2$$
$$x \ge 0$$

Now, I substituted spherical coordinates. From the second equation I got that $r \in [0,a]$. From the third equation I got that $\phi \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

But, as for the third equation, I am only getting this:

$$\sin^2\phi \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = \cos^2\phi \sin^2\theta$$

Now, the best thing I can do here is divide both sides by $\sin^2\theta$ and I get that

$$\sin^2\phi + \cot^2\theta = \cos^2\phi$$

Which brings me to

$$\cot\theta = \sqrt{\cos(2\phi)}.$$

Is this correct? But even if it is, I'd have to take the inverse cotangent function to get the upper bound for $\theta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the axis of symmetry for the cone is along x-axis, please define spherical coordinates with second polar axis being x-axis.

$y = \rho \cos\theta \sin \phi, z = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, x = \rho \cos\phi$

Then cone is $\tan \phi = 1 \implies 0 \leq \phi \leq \dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Bounds of $\rho$ from the equation of the sphere:
$0 \leq \rho \leq a$

$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

So the integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \int_0^a \rho^4 \sin \phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta$

Comment: Alternative to changing the spherical coordinates in this method is just to change the area of integration, due to symmetry of the function and the area you can rotate it to the z-axis just as easilly.

Comment: What a powerful solution, @MathLover! Thank you!

Comment: @l0ner9 thank you. These are pretty standard tricks that I am sure you will start using pretty soon with practice yourself. When we are in school, most problems are written such that we keep second polar along z-axis and we just get used to it so much that feels like that's the only way one can define spherical coordinates :) I hope you are clear on $x \geq 0$ bit. That only tells that we should not consider the volume bound by the other cone below YZ-plane.